# Java increment declaration in for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
public class F2E12 {

    public static final int DIM = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printMatrix(DIM);

    }

    public static void printMatrix(int n) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for(;i<=n;i++) {
            for(;j<=n;j++) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");

        }
    }
}
```

I want to print a matrix which increments the first number of each row by one.
The above code should produce:

1. 0 1 2 3 4 5
2. 1 0 1 2 3 4
3. 2 1 0 1 2 3
4. 3 2 1 0 3 4
5. 4 3 2 1 0 1
6. 5 4 3 2 1 0

Instead it prints. "0 1 2 3 4 5"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code doesn't work because `j` hits `n` on the first iteration of `i`. You could move `j` into the loop like

```
// int j = 0;
for (; i <= n; i++) {
    int j = 0;
    for (; j <= n; j++) {
```

to fix that.

Answer (score 7):

```
public static void printMatrix(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            System.out.print(Math.abs(j - i) + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```